# Android Google Map SDK Toolbar issue -- not launching external map

Tags: android, google-maps, targetsdkversion

The app has a Google Map built-in by using Maps SDK. Tapping one of the icons on the Map Toolbar should launch the external Maps app.

[image]

The launching of the external Maps app had been working well until targetSDKVersion=29.
When targetSDKVersion=30, the launching failed, and the screen showed this message:
Google Maps is not installed or is disabled.

Why is that?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, seems like an Maps SDK for Android issue. Would mind filing a bug for this on [Google's Public Issue Tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188870)?

Comment: Hi i have the same problem at the moment. Did you find any solution to fix this yet ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**EDIT**: This issue should be fixed in version 17.0.1 of the library. You can refer to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#april_27_2021).

I work in Developer Relations for Google Maps. This issue is due to package visibility requirements introduced in Android 11. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility). Essentially, your app needs to declare in the `AndroidManifest.xml` all the packages it requires to function correctly.

To fix this, you will need to add the Google Maps package "com.google.android.apps.maps" as an entry in your `AndroidManifest.xml` `<queries>` entry:

```
<manifest package="com.your.package">
  <queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

You can also refer to our [sample](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/main/ApiDemos/kotlin/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L19...L21).

Comment: Hi Chris. I just happened to stumble upon this issue. What's the deal with the new beta sdk not being updated in over a year?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Additionally, it is necessary to upgrade Gradle to 3.5.4 to avoid the error "Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at AndroidManifest.xml...". Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67820136/9686461

Comment: i was stuck in this  for very long time. Thank you so much @Chris Arriola

Comment: thanks i was stuck with this problem too