# "Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-64"

Tags: flutter, dart, payment

Actually I published a app in play store, in the next update I want to add UPI payments in the app. So, I am using upi_pay package. When I installing the package getting error as "Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-64". Can someone help me in this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This issue happens for the combination of:

- Using Android-SDK's API level 31 (or later),
- With old Gradle version(s).

> Basically, updating build-tools to 31 is not enough to support `queries` element (of manifest, added since Android 11+). Gradle needs to be updated, too.

It worked for me when I upgraded Gradle from `3.5.0` to `3.5.4`.

In root `build.gradle` file, like:

```
// ...

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

// ...
```

Comment: saved mine also :-)

Comment: thanks man appreciated....

Comment: Thnx. Worked for me too.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[@Phanindra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67820136/9167102) thank for answering

but also downgrade package version to `stripe_payment: ^1.1.0` for safety, because above this all versions are discontinued

[image]